# publich asp.net mvc web site to server

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I publich asp.net mvc web site to server.and after that I made some changes in it, and I want to republish it.
I republish the mvc control but, it does not work.

should I republish the whole web site when I update the code in one of mvc controls??

Comment: the code of all controllers in your mvc application must be in dll, so that you need copy dll to server

Comment: thank you. where I can found it and what does it called?

Comment: dll is in bin folder, and his name is the same as your mcv project.

Comment: It does not work. I also try to republish the bin folder but nothing change.

Comment: I means when I republish the bin folder,nothing change. It seems that the old control still work.

Comment: try to reset iis and push crtl + F5 to refresh the page